# bitset for more than 32 bits?

Tags: c++, stl, bitset

I need to use bit flags with more than 32 bits (33 to be exact right now). I tried and find std::bitset doesn't handle more than 32 bits (ulong). Do I have to use vector or there's a way to make bitset to work?

I am limited to c++98 in this project so I can't use boost.

Thanks.

Edit:

I'd like to do something like this:

```
const uint64    kBigNumber = 1LL << 33;
std::bitset<33> myBitSet;
...
switch(myBitSet) {
    case kBigNumber:
    // do something
    ...
}
```

Comment: Presumably you will need to be doing multiple bitset operations on individual 32-bit values?

Comment: Actually, I'd like to be able to do bitwise operation between bitsets and 64-bit constants. Something like if(my33bitset & kA64bitConst) {...}. Also the ability to use the 64 bit consts in switch statement's case clause will be great.

Comment: How could you possibly be limited to C++98?

Comment: @DeadMG: This is a legacy project that I can't do much about the build process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just retested `std::bitset` with 65 bits and on my 32-bit Linux it works fine and as expected.

Notable exception is the `to_ulong()` method which throws exception if any set bit would be truncated during the conversion. Now I think about it and that is rather obvious: there is no other way as to prevent application from getting truncated data. And the behavior [is also documented](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/bitset.html).

---

To the *Edit* with switch/case. Why do you need `std::bitset` then? You platform apparently already supports 64 bit numbers - use them. `std::bitset` is designed to be used as [an light-weight bit array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array) with static memory allocation. It is not intended to be used as a replacement for number.

Comment: I am using plain 64-bit unsigned right now. I am exploring different ways to do it and also to plan for the future where the flags can be more than 64 bits.

Comment: You can use only integer types for switch/case in C/C++. `uint64_t` (or whatever widest integer type your compiler supports) is as far you would be able to jump on 32bit arch. And more then 64 flags - this sounds like a bad idea. Ask here on SO how to avoid that.

Answer (score 6):

`std::bitset` should work with more or less arbitrary sizes -- it's *not* normally limited to the size of an unsigned long (though it can look that way, because there's a constructor that builds a bitset based on the bits in an unsigned long).

If that won't work, `vector<bool>` may be useful for you, though you should be aware that it's pretty much a `vector` in name only -- it is *not* really a container (i.e., doesn't conform to the normal container requirements).

Answer (score 5):

Would `std::vector<bool>` work for you?  It can be resized, is reasonably fast and has a small footprint.  It's also part of the STL.

Comment: Yet not STL-compliant, excitingly

Answer (score 1):

You can use the to_string on your bitset and covert it back using strtoull

```
const uint64    kBigNumber = 1LL << 33;
std::bitset<33> myBitSet;
...
unsigned long long bitSetLong = strtoull(myBitSet.to_string<char,char_traits<char>,allocator<char> >().c_str(), NULL, 2);
switch(bitSetLong) {
    case kBigNumber:
    // do something
    ...
}
```

Note the above can work only till 64 bits.